# SQL single query

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

prod_cat_info

[image]

transactions

[image]

I want to fetch the combined revenue earned from the 'Electronics', 'Clothing' categories from, 'Flagship store'.

where, Electronics and clothing are under Prod_cat_info table under ptod_cat with 3 and 5 as their prod_cat_code whereas, Flagship store is in transactions table under store_type.

Please help. The code i am using is

Select T.Prod_cat_code,
Sum(T.Total_amt) as revenue
From TRANSACTIONS T
LEFT JOIN PROD_CAT_INFO PC ON T.Prod_cat_code = PC.Prod_cat_code
WHERE T.store_type = 'Flagship store' AND (T.prod_cat_code = 3 OR T.prod_cat_code = 1)
Group By 
T.Prod_cat_code;

This is perhaps giving me a wrong sum.

Comment: What query did you write for this? What issue you are facing? Can you share some sample data of tables and the expected output?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you do not really need the prod_cat_info table if you already have the data in the transaction table maybe through a foreign key. This query should help with your results.

```
SELECT SUM(T.total_amt)
transactions T
WHERE T.store_type = 'Flagship store' AND (T.prod_cat_code = 3 OR T.prod_cat_code = 5);
```

Comment: i do need prod_cat_info table since the transaction table just have the prod_cat_code and to identify the prod_cat_code for electronics and clothing i have to refer prod_cat_info table since transaction table just have the code i.e. 3 and 5 and not the names of the code i.e. electronics and clothing

Comment: It looks like you are referencing the prod_cat_info table through transaction in the picture above.